# iOS 16.1.2 Deleting data and browsing history does not work for Safari

Tags: safari, web-browsing, auto-complete, browser-history

Where other than in Safari settings can I delete the browsing history auto-complete function. Clearing browsing history, data, and closing tabs doesn't work.

My search engine is set to “duckduckgo”. These website suggestion auto-completes are sometimes old and dead websites that I may have visited 5+ years ago.

Comment: I finally figured it out after asking bing chat.  Thanks

Comment: Glad you found your answer!